# What is the Gaussian universality class of phase transitions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition

In [arXiv:1705.09309](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09309v1) it is said that Bose-Einstein condensation in ideal gas belongs to the Gaussian universality class.

**What is the Gaussian universality class of phase transitions?**

I know that a universality class is determined (with some exceptions) by a symmetry group of the order parameter leaving the Hamiltonian intact ($\mathbb{Z}_2$ for Ising, $O(2)$ for XY, permutation group for the Potts model etc.) and by dimensionality of the system.

**What symmetry is obeyed by the order parameter and what is a typical/canonical form of the Hamiltonian in the case of Gaussian universality class?**